# Swagger schema reference in another file

Tags: yaml, swagger

I'm working on huge yaml schema when I'm designing my swagger API service model and emphasized textI would like to save the `model` part in another file in order to have more flexibility and lisibility.

Following [this](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/using-ref/) documentation, I used this part of code :

```
components:
  schemas:
    Request:
      title: Request
      type: object
      properties:
        technicalData:
          $ref: '../../schemas/foo.yaml/components/schemas/TechnicalData'
```

And in my `foo.yaml` file, I have stuff like this :

```
components:
  schemas:
    TechnicalData:
      type: object
      properties:
        application:
          type: string
        applicationCode:
          type: string
        userId:
          type: string
```

It works on localhost, but I face the following issue running my file on the enterprise deployement server :

> Errors
> Resolver error at
> components.schemas.Request.properties.technicalData.$ref Could not
> resolve reference because of: Not Acceptable

I am sucessfully able to browse my file through the browser locally.

Checking on the internet, I found some issue related to my topic, but unfortunately not very usefull :
https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-editor/issues/1561

https://github.com/RepreZen/KaiZen-OpenAPI-Editor/issues/438

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Add `#` between the file name and `/components/...`:

```yaml
$ref: '../../schemas/foo.yaml#/components/schemas/TechnicalData'
                             ^
```

Comment: It was just that simple. I keep the issue open waiting for the deployement in order to validate it works on the server